# set cell values while cloning rows of a table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I dynamically create rows. I want to clone them, and while they are cloned also fill specific cells (e.g. the 2nd cell of each row) with values (e.g. from an array).

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
var clone;

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   clone = row.cloneNode(true);
   table.appendChild(clone);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for now. Based on that I need to fill input elements. The complete code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
var clone;

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  table.appendChild(clone);

}


var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].innerText = "test";
}
```